# Neo4j fuzzy search

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4

In my Spring Data Neo4j 4 project Neo4j database I have a `Product` nodes with `name` and `description` string properties.

I need to add fuzzy search functionality over these properties. Is there any out of the box functionality in Neo4j/Spring Data Neo4j in order to implement this ? If yes/no could you please suggest how it can be implemented ?

Comment: I don't think there is - there are regexes in Cypher but that's about it.

Comment: currently, no... you might want to add elastic search to the mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a repository called:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {

    List<Product> findByNameLike(String name);

    List<Product> findByDescriptionLike(String description);
}
```

You can then do something like this (since 4.2.0):

```
List<Product> products = productRepository.findByNameLike("*on*");
```

which will do a wildcard match using regular expressions (see Cypher `=~` operator).

The negated version of this; name `findByNameNotLike()` is also supported.